# fundamental theorem of calculus involving multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{f(x)}g(t)dt=g(f(x))f'(x)$$ with the appropriate prerequisites ($g$ is continuous and real-valued, etc).

1)By some counterexamples (for example $\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}(t+x)dt$) we can easily know that the statement $\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{f(x)}g(t,x)dt=g(f(x),x)f'(x)$ is false. Why, though? Or is this the wrong question to ask? It was never correct in the first place and the question should never have been raised?

2)Suppose $u=q(x)$. Then if $$F(x)=\int_{a}^{q(x)}g(t,x)dt$$, let $$P(u,x)=\int_{a}^{u}g(t,x)dt$$

Then, $$\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial u}=g(u,x)$$

I can't really get the logic behind this-- is this something to do with differentiating under the integral sign? But that wouldn't work, would it? $u$ is not a constant-it's a function, isn't it?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

We have that $$P(u,x) = \int_a^u g(t,x)\,{\rm d}t \implies \frac{\partial P}{\partial u}(u,x) = g(u,x) \quad\mbox{and}\quad \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(u,x) = \int_a^u \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,x)\,{\rm d}t.$$The first derivative is just the fundamental theorem of Calculus without anything else behind the scenes, because $x$ is frozen! The second equality is indeed differentiation under the integral sign, and holds provided $g$ is smooth enough.

If you want to compute the derivative of $$F(x) = \int_a^{q(x)}g(t,x)\,{\rm d}x,$$a chain rule is required. Because $F(x) = P(q(x),x)$, so $$F'(x) = q'(x)\frac{\partial P}{\partial u}(q(x),x) + 1\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(q(x),x).$$This means that $$F'(x) = q'(x)g(q(x),x) + \int_a^{q(x)} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,x)\,{\rm d}t.$$Keeping track of all evaluation points helps you understand better what is going on.

Comment: In your second derivative, why can you differentiate under the integral sign? $u$ is not a constant, is it?